# Call a nested function in Python

Tags: python, function, nested-function

Is it possible to call a nested function defined inside an existing function:

For example:

```
def first(x):
    def second():
        print(x)
    return second
```

I know I can do something like this: `first(10)()`

Yet I want to do something similar to this:

```
first(10).second()
```

My thinking is that it is not possible because `second` does not exist until `first` is called.

Am I right?

Comment: You should consider using a class instead.

Comment: Even more, `second` doesn't exist outside `first` scope. Consider using a class instead

Comment: You could return an *object* with a method named `second()`, but why not make `first()` a class to begin with? (Example: `def first(x): return str(x)`, then `first(10).upper()` would work, because strings have a method named `upper()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want, you can return several functions that way:

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self,**kw): vars(self).update(kw)
def first(x):
    def second():
        print(x)
    def third(y): return x+y
    return Box(second=second,third=third)

first(10).second()   # prints 10
x=first(15)
x.second()           # prints 15
print(x.third(10))   # prints 25
```

Any resemblance to reputation scores for answers is coincidental.

Comment: How is this better than defining `first` to be a class? It seems to be doing the same thing in a less idiomatic way.

Comment: I've used it when `first` was a method; changing it to a class would require passing `self` around explicitly and wreak havoc with code organization and/or indentation.  This technique also lets you naturally have a set of "methods" that is variable.  I'm not claiming it should be anyone's first choice.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Well, that could be a better answer yet I wanted first to be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a class?

```
class First:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def second(self):
        print(x)

First(3).second()
```

The fact that all Python functions are closures is a great feature, but it's fairly advanced. Classes are the usual place to store state.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not the right way but just for fun.
What you are doing here is returning the instance of the second function, so while calling it, no dont need to call it by name, jsut use the variable.

```
def first(x):
    def second():
        print(x)

    return second

x = first(10)
x()
```

or like this

```
first(10)()
```

as mention by other, use `class` instead.

Comment: This isn't "just for fun": it's how lots of higher-order functional programming is done in Python.

Comment: yes, you are right @DavisHerring closure is widely used in python, but for this type of cases, I prefer to use the class. :)